# DJANGO - RelatedObjectDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a problem with classic heritages :

**my models :**

```
class Scribe(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{ "+self.user.username+" } "

class membre(Scribe): 
    def __str__(self):
        return "{ pseudo :"+self.user.username+" } "
```

In shell I do this :

- u=User.objects.create_user(username="lala")
- s=Scribe(u)
- m=membre(s)

But when I do this in the shell : m or m.user.username I have this error :

**RelatedObjectDoesNotExist : Scribe has no user**

Comment: Be sure to save these records, otherwise there is no primary key value to establish a relationship. Also, if you intend for membre to be a proxy for Scribe instead of a separate type of record, you should use proxy=True in the model Meta. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#proxy

Answer (score 0):

Add `Scribe` as a foreign key to `membre`:

```
class Scribe(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{ " + self.user.username + " } "

class membre(models.Model):
    scribe = models.ForeignKey(Scribe)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{ pseudo :" + self.scribe.user.username + " } "
```

And then you can instantiate both models with `create` method:

```
u = User.objects.create_user(username="lala")
s = Scribe.objects.create(user=u)
m = membre.objects.create(scribe=s)

print s
print m
```

Comment: No I don't want get proxy functionality. I want the membre have the same attributes than Scribe and display this attributes

Comment: With you models `Scribe` will be automatically created when you will create `membre`. Is it desired behaviour or these models should be totally independent from each other?

Comment: Totally independent ( I performed tests and the problem is in the OneToOneField...)

Comment: I'm sorry but I want membre have Scribe in attribute and not always write the same attribute than Scribe. I think I put Scribe foreign key in membre

Comment: I dont understand because the error message is Scribe has no user and when I do this : m.scribe.user = User.objects.create_... , it's clean ! (m is instance of membre)

Comment: Ok but it's sad because I don't use heritage.. Thank's